# How to invoke an event asynchronously?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, asynchronous

I'm building a control that will be used by other developers, and in a few places I have events that the developer can subscribe to do some potentially long operations.

My goal is to give them the option to use async/await, multithreading, backgroundworkers etc. *if they choose*, but still be able to complete the execution before the event invocation completes. Here's a psuedo-code example (I realize this doesn't compile, but hopefully the intention is clear):

My Code:

```
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
private void InvokeMyEvent()
{
    var args = new MyEventArgs();

    // Keep the UI responsive until this returns
    await MyEvent?.Invoke(this, args);

    // Then show the result
    MessageBox.Show(args.Result);
}
```

Developer's/subscriber's potential code:

```
// Option 1: The operation is very quick,
// so the dev doesn't mind doing it synchronously
private void myForm_MyEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    // Short operation, I'll just do it right here.
    string result = DoQuickOperation();
    e.Result = result;
}

// Option 2, The operation is long,
// so the dev wants to do it on another thread and keep the UI responsive.
private void myForm_MyEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    myForm.ShowProgressPanel();

    // Long operation, I want to multithread this!
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string result = DoVeryLongOperation();
        e.Result = result;
    })
    .ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        myForm.HideProgressPanel();
    }
}
```

Is there any standard way to accomplish this? I was looking at the delegate's BeginInvoke and EndInvoke methods hoping they would help, but I didn't really come up with anything.

Any help or advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Will every subscriber always have a result?

Comment: Realistically there will only be one subscriber, but if there are multiple I only care about the last one. If they don't set it, the result is just whatever MyEventArgs constructs it as.

Comment: You need two changes: (1) **The handlers need to return `Task`** so that the calling code has a way to know when they're done. (2) You can't use syntactic sugar to ignore the number of subscribed handlers.  Not only will `?.Invoke` not work because it leaves you trying to await a `null` when there are no handlers, multicast won't work either.  **You need to call `GetInvocationList()` and loop.**  Even if the last handler is the one that gets the privilege of determining the value of `args.Result`, you still need to wait on the `Task` objects returned from the others.

Comment: 1) Does that not break convention for event handlers? It would also force the developer to return a task even if they don't use one. 2) Sure, makes sense, but I'd need them to execute and return one after another which can't be done this way.

Comment: 1) Too bad, you asked for something that is not possible without breaking convention.  2) I just told you how to do it, so don't tell me it can't be done.  It's up to you whether you wait on the first `Task` before obtaining the second... but if you let the async handlers run in parallel, you have no control over the order in which changes to `args.Result` happen.

Comment: "You asked for something that is not possible without breaking convention." I asked if there *was* a convention, you suggested breaking the convention. But anyway, if there is no proper way to do this, I'm open to alternative routes to accomplish my stated goal.

Comment: @BenVoigt You can give each handler their own copy of the arguments if it's important that they not fight with each other over it; it's then up to you to do whatever you want with all of the results.  The other option is to just have the `Task` from each handler be a `Task<T>`, and get the results that way.

Answer (score 8):

There is no standard way of doing this.

My personal preference, when I was in this situation, was to use a custom delegate type returning `Task`. Handlers which return synchronously can simply return `Task.CompletedTask`, they don't need to create a new task for this.

```
public delegate Task MyAsyncEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);
public event MyAsyncEventHandler MyEvent;
private async Task InvokeMyEvent()
{
    var args = new MyEventArgs();

    // Keep the UI responsive until this returns
    var myEvent = MyEvent;
    if (myEvent != null)
        await Task.WhenAll(Array.ConvertAll(
          myEvent.GetInvocationList(),
          e => ((MyAsyncEventHandler)e).Invoke(this, args)));

    // Then show the result
    MessageBox.Show(args.Result);
}
```

Note the capture of `myEvent` in a local variable to avoid threading issues, and the use of `GetInvocationList()` to ensure all tasks are awaited.

Note that in this implementation, if you have multiple event handlers, they are all scheduled at once so may execute in parallel. The handlers need to ensure they do not access `args` in thread-unsafe ways.

Depending on your use case, executing the handlers sequentially (`await` in a loop) could be more appropriate.

Comment: Thread-safety is not the issue with access to `args`, because concurrency between `async` tasks is cooperative switching, not true parallelism.  But being safe against reordering and re-entrance would be important.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thread-safety is an issue, because a background thread could unsubscribe an event handler after `if (MyEvent != null)` was checked, but before `MyEvent.GetInvocationList()` was called. This is a well-known problem with event handlers even with the standard signature.

Comment: Well, that's an entirely different issue to how `args` is accessed, which is your statement that I intended my comment to apply to.

Comment: For that matter, the invocation list also has problems with switching and reentrancy not just threading.

Comment: @BenVoigt Since they're all called from the UI thread all of the stuff running on that UI thread will be sequential, but any actual parallel work that any of the handlers do that don't require being on the UI thread would happen in parallel (unless they specifically did something to do otherwise).  Specifically the actual examples that the OP showed would result in some work done in parallel.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, okay, misunderstood your comment, but then thread-safety is still an issue: if you have two event handlers, and they both `await` some other operation (or call `task.ContinueWith` in their implementation directly), their continuations may execute in parallel on two different background threads.

Comment: @hvd Not if they use `await`.  The code is running in the UI thread, so they'd be synchronized through the synchronization context.  If they used ConfigureAwait(false) (or `ContinueWith`, as the OP's code does) then yeah, they'd use a thread pool thread.

Comment: @Servy Generally, yes, and I should have edited my comment to cover that. `await Task.Run(...)` is another rather likely way in which background threads may access `args`, which the OP is also using.

Comment: @hvd For handing the result specifically, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379046/how-to-invoke-an-event-asynchronously/45379223?noredirect=1#comment77720294_45379046), you should really just have the tasks be `Task<T>` and get the result that way.

Comment: @Servy Sure, that's possible. Personally, I'd prefer not to, as it strays even further from how event handlers have been designed, and I try to follow conventions unless there's a compelling reason not to. It would make a good alternative answer that the OP might well go for though.

Comment: @hvd Mutating a passed in parameter to get the results of an asynchronous operation is not only not a convention, it's an explicit *anti-pattern*, which would be worse than something that's just a unconventional.  If you do use the argument though, you'll at least want to do it right, for example, by giving each caller their own argument list, as also mentioned in the comment.

Comment: @Servy Mutating a passed in parameter *in an event handler* to return a result most definitely is a Microsoft convention.

Comment: @hvd There are *rare* instances where handlers have some mutable state provided in a *synchronous* (rather than asynchronous) handler.  They're generally not "the result" of the handler, in the sense that they're not required, as they are here, but rather something that can optionally be mutated in occasionally needed instances.  As has been mentioned earlier (by yourself even), the whole situation is unusual and doesn't fit into standard practices, trying to apply some here is just harming the solution, not helping it.

Comment: @Servy, if you're curious about my specific case, I am using the event to pass a large DataTable to the dev, and I want them to be able to optionally replace the DataTable with their own, so that's why I need the event args mutable. I realize it's unusual with async, but it's a typical pattern for event handlers.

Comment: @Servy One case where I'd describe it as a result of an event handler is the `BindingList<T>.AddingNew` event. .NET has other similar examples. Anyway, after AnotherProgrammer's comment, it doesn't matter, I'd call that a mutation too.

Comment: @hvd And one where it's going to be problematic to have multiple handlers all mutating the data table at the same time, given your solution.

Comment: @Servy Mentioned as an issue in my answer, and trivially solvable though, for instance by having `MyAsyncEventArgs` provide a lock object that the handlers can use to synchronise access.

Answer (score 4):

You may find my [blog post on async events](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html) useful.

There is no strict convention, but there is a loose convention due to the way the WinRT/Win10 APIs handled this problem: deferrals. I have a [`DeferralManager` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Oop/DeferralManager.cs) that helps out here:

```
class MyEventArgs : IDeferralSource
{
  private IDeferralSource _deferralSource;
  public MyEventArgs(IDeferralSource deferralSource) { _deferralSource = deferralSource; }
  IDisposable GetDeferral() => _deferralSource.GetDeferral();

  ... // Other properties
}

public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
private async Task InvokeMyEventAsync()
{
  var deferralManager = new DeferralManager();
  var args = new MyEventArgs(deferralManager.DeferralSource);

  MyEvent?.Invoke(this, args);

  await deferralManager.WaitForDeferralsAsync();

  MessageBox.Show(args.Result);
}
```

This approach has the nice property that synchronous event handlers are exactly like normal, while allowing asynchronous event handlers. But it's not ideal; in particular, there's nothing that *forces* an asynchronous event handler to acquire a deferral - and if it doesn't, then it won't work as expected.

However, I must caution you that using events for this kind of a design is suspect in the first place. In .NET, events are an appropriate implementation of the Observer design pattern. But your code isn't using Observer; it's using the Template Method design pattern. The design problems you're running into are because you're attempting to use events to implement the Template Method design pattern. You can force it to fit (in a few different ways), but it won't be ideal.

Comment: Hi thanks for the idea. In response to your last paragraph, do you suggest an alternative route? If it helps, one specific case is that I'm loading a DataTable, and just before I do stuff to it, I invoke this event to allow a subscriber to either modify the DataTable, or provide a custom one of their own instead via MyEventArgs. I then use this DataTable in the rest of my code.

Comment: You can either use inheritance, where `MyEvent` becomes `virtual Task UpdateDataDable(DataTable x);`, or you can use composition, where `MyEvent` becomes an instance of `IDataTableUpdater { Task UpdateDataTable(DataTable x); }` that is passed into the constructor of your type. I prefer composition, personally.

Comment: Sadly I don't think either of those options work for me as this code is on a Control... that's on a Control... that's on a Control. I expose my events on the top level control for convenience as the child controls are intentionally private.

Comment: I don't see why these approaches wouldn't work. Especially the composition one - private derived types get unweildly.